# How can I access models from another solution in the same ASP.NET MVC 4 project

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-relationship

I have a project containing two solutions, I want to access some of the models in solution a when I was working on solution B. How can I access solution A's Models? Can anyone Help please

Comment: Solutions contain projects, not the other way around. If you mean you have multiple projects, you need to add a project reference to your consuming project so they can get a reference to those models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add the `SolutionA.ProjectWithModels.csproj` as an existing project into `SolutionB`.

Just keep in mind that the Visual Studio will most likely warn you about the project not being part of `SolutionB` folder structure, but if you can guarantee that `SolutionA.ProjectWithModels.csproj` will always be available when opening `SolutionB` then that might be an option.

Another option could be to copy the generated `SolutionA.ProjectWithModels` assembly and reference it in `SolutionB.Mvc4Project` or maybe create a separate solution/project for those models and create a `NuGet` package from it which you can then install in `SolutionB.Mvc4Project`

Comment: In terms of engineering, you definitely want to treat one as a dependency of the other.  Having a project referenced from more than one solution causes the dependency to be compiled from two different places, making your runtime non-deterministic.  The dependency should be pulled in from a version aware source.

Comment: @chappoo yep, completely agree. Of all the options above is the NuGet one the most stable and maintainable one. The other ones are just alternatives in case a NuGet approach would not be feasible/acceptable, of course with all the possible drawbacks...

Comment: I was able to add a solution reference to Project B and that solved the problem.